# Regex to select NOT and operand

Tags: regex

I am trying to break a string to array using Regex in C# .
I have for example the string

```
 {([Field] = '100' OR [LaneDescription] LIKE '%DENTINPALEUW%' 
 OR [LaneDescription] = 'asdf' OR ([ObjectID] = 1) AND [ITEM_HEIGHT] >= 
 10 AND [SENDER_COMPANY] NOT LIKE '%DHL%'}
```

(Generated from Telerik RadFilter)

and i need it broken so i can pass it to a custom object with types: open parenthesis, field, comparator , value,  close parenthesis.

So far and with the help of http://regexr.com i have reached to

```
\[([^\[\]]*)\]+|[\w'%]+|[()=]
```

but i need to get the '>=' and 'NOT LIKE' as one (and similar values like <> != etc..)

You can see my late night attempts at http://regexr.com/39g6b

Any help would be much appreciated.

(PS: There are no newline characters at the string)

Comment: Why use Regex and not the string methods available? C# is really good manipulating strings with the String class. e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c7h58e5(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Because i need it as an array of strings like '>=' , 'NOT LIKE' , '>' ,'(' etc....i don't want it as a char array because i will have to create about 100 ifs to do what i need

Comment: You could use LINQ to get what you need from an array

Comment: Could you write an example based on the string i have posted above? i need an array with ( , [FieldName] , Operator , 'Value' / Value }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
\(|\)|\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\]|'.*?'|\d+|NOT LIKE|\w+|[=><!]+
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/jY0bS7/1)

Explanation:

```
    \( // match "(" literally
    | // or
    \) // ")"
    | // or
    \[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\] // any words inside square braces []
    |
    '.*?' // strings enclosed in single quotes '' (escape sequences can easily trip this up though)
    |
    \d+ // digits
    |
    NOT LIKE // "NOT LIKE", because this is the only token that can contain whitespace
    |
    \w+ // words like "NOT", "AND", etc
    |
    [=><!]+ // operators like ">", "!=", etc
```